# Add accelerator description to JMenuItem in GUI, without actually adding an accelerator

Tags: java, swing, jmenuitem

I'm trying to set some text to be displayed where the accelerator binding is usually displayed, for a `JMenuItem`.
The demarcated <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd> text in the following image is an example of what I'm trying to set, for another `JMenuItem`.

[image: accelerator text example]

I *don't* actually want to set an accelerator for this `JMenuItem`, though. 
I've poked around the source for several classes, like `JMenuItem` and `BasicMenuItemUI`, to no avail.
What's the simplest way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: There, actually isn't one.  From memory, the `JMenuItem` is a proxy for what is displayed, and the `JMenu` actually generates the view itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the reason you want this is so you can prevent the menu from triggering the undo action a second time, when the key combination is already bound on a component on the frame, but this shouldn't be necessary. If the component consumes the key event, the menu won't detect it.

Here's an example with a JTextArea to see what I mean:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

JMenuBar menu = new JMenuBar();
frame.setJMenuBar(menu);
JMenu menuEdit = new JMenu("Edit");
menu.add(menuEdit);
JMenuItem menuEditUndo = new JMenuItem("Undo");
menuEdit.add(menuEditUndo);
menuEditUndo.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("control Z"));
menuEditUndo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("menu");
    }
});

JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(20, 40);
textArea.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("control Z"), "undo");
textArea.getActionMap().put("undo", new AbstractAction() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("text");
    }
});
frame.add(new JScrollPane(textArea));

frame.pack();
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Both the text area and the menu item have bound to the same key combo, but pressing <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd> while the text area has focus prints only "text" and never "menu". I.e., the action does not happen twice. Although this uses a JTextArea, it should be true of any component.