# JavaFX disable accelerator action

Tags: java, swing, javafx

I have MenuItem ,

```
 MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem("OP");
 menuItem.setAccelerator(KeyCombination.keyCombination("Ctrl+S"));
```

I want to display only the text(Ctrl+S) and not have any **action** for the accelerator, because i have `keyBindings` for that.With both in place the action occurs twice.

I found a similar question, 
[[Add accelerator description to JMenuItem in GUI, without actually adding an accelerator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23818977/add-accelerator-description-to-jmenuitem-in-gui-without-actually-adding-an-acce][1])

But it is for **Swing**.

How can i do this in **JavaFX**.

Comment: If you add an accelerator, why don't you simply remove the keybinding?

Comment: @DVarga It is for a totally different scenario i have key bindings, now that key bindings covers all i want to remove accelerator action.

Comment: Could you post your whole `Menu` and/or everything that makes me able to understand what's going on there?:)

Comment: @DVarga http://stackoverflow.com/q/39588765/3164187 The post for actual issue.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
Scene scene = ...;
stage.setScene(scene);
stage.show();
scene.getAccelerators().clear();
```

The help text is displayed, but the action does not fire on key press.